# Inserting records to an interface

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-design, interface, sql-server-2000

I have set up a stored procedure for inserting a single record into a table. The reason for this is to create a general interface for people to use so I can change the table structure that it points to without anyone noticing or having to change code on their end in the future.

The problem occurs when the user has to insert many records. Normally they would be able to do an INSERT statement which inserts many records at once but with this interface they are forced to loop through each record, inserting it individually. Speed is not the biggest factor here, accessibility is.

I have considered using a view but I'm not sure how well this would work. I'm simply not familiar enough with them to know for sure. Also, queries from other servers may be accessing the interface and I don't think views allow you to insert from another server.

What would you suggest I do?

Comment: Whoa, I had no idea.  Do you have a link where I can find more information?

Comment: @Abe - Don't know any particularly good resource but if you google `updatable views` you should find plenty of stuff. I think they could be a good fit here - but I see this is tagged SQL Server 2000 so maybe not! Also I'm not sure of any limitation on inserting into an updatable view from another server. I've never come across that myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 stored procedures. One uses SQL Server's BULK INSERT and the other one is your standard one for inserting one record (you already have this).  Your users can call either one depending on their needs.

For more info on BULK INSERT
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: I don't understand how the bulk insert solves the problem. How do you "pass in" the records?

Comment: bulk insert needs a file.  Here is an example:

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-bulk-insert-to-load-a-text-file

Comment: Using a file isn't going to solve the problem. The problem isn't that I have a huge amount of records, it's that I don't want the users to have to rewrite their programs to use a loop instead of an INSERT statement while accessing the interface

Comment: I don't think that you can insert multiple data records with one SQL Server "INSERT" statement. SQL Server 2008 might have something for that, but not 2005 and 2000.

Here is a trick that you can try.  I don't know how well it will perform:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/08/sql-server-insert-multiple-records-using-one-insert-statement-use-of-union-all/

Comment: When I say "insert multiple records at once" I mean like this: INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2, ...)
SELECT column3, column4, ...
FROM table2

Comment: So the records are coming from a different table (table2). That simplifies the problem. You can use a "SELECT INTO" statement: http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_select_into.asp

Comment: I don't want to give the users access to the table. The whole point is to use an interface so I can modify the back end when needed.

Comment: I understand that. What are the parameters to your interface method(s)?

If you control the concrete implemenation, then why can't you change it to use BULK INSERT?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [SQLBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class.  This seems to do what you are looking for.

Comment: I thought about that one too, this assumes he is using a .NET language.

Comment: The users can use whatever language they want. They do not have access to the table itself (the point of the interface...)

Comment: When you say users are you referring to other programmers?  Can you expand on what you mean by "interface"?

Comment: I want other programmers to program to an interface. http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciples.html